# doxygen misrendering macro type as public member function

Tags: c, macros, doxygen

I'm using a type macro `list(type)` which expands to a dynamic type [ `list_of_type` ] like below :

**main snippet**

```
...
#define list(type) force_append_macro(list_of_,type)
...
typedef struct _improperlydocumented
{
  list(char_ptr) *words;
}improperlydocumented;
...
```

**problem**

> doxygen is incorrectly rendering this type [ `list(char_ptr)` ] as a
>   public member function ( instead of member data ).

**environmental information**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

$ doxygen --version
1.8.6
```

doxygen wizard generates following output :

[`doxygen -g`](http://www.wepaste.com/doxygen%20-g/)

my code/config :

---

**doxygen.config**

```
PROJECT_NAME           = "doxytest"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./build/docs
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES

TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = YES

HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = NO
INPUT                  = ./
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h *.c

GENERATE_HTML          = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO

ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             =
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      =
```

note: i tried setting `EXPAND_AS_DEFINED = list`; with same output as below..

**list.h**

```
#ifndef __list__
#define __list__

typedef struct 
{
  int capacity,
      count,
      objsize,
      xprate;
  void *data;
}glist_t;

/* allow list types to be defined (as wrappers around generic_list) */
#define append_macro(a,b) a ## b
#define force_append_macro(a,b) append_macro(a,b)
#define declare_named_list_type(name,type) typedef union\
                                           {struct force_append_macro(_template_,name)\
                                             {\
                                               int capacity,\
                                               count,\
                                               objsize,\
                                               xprate;\
                                               type *data;\
                                             }template;\
                                             glist_t ls;\
                                           }name
#define declare_list_type(type) declare_named_list_type(force_append_macro(list_of_,type),type)
#define list(type) force_append_macro(list_of_,type)

typedef char * char_ptr;
declare_list_type(char_ptr);

/*!
 * This object is improperly documented.
 *
 * Issue is that the list(char_ptr) is treated as a member function instead of a type..
 */

typedef struct _improperlydocumented
{
  list(char_ptr) *words;
}improperlydocumented;

#endif
```

**doxygen output**

> ### improperlydocumented Struct Reference
>
> ---
>
> #include <list.h>
>
> ### Public Member Functions
>
> ---
>
> ```
> list (char_ptr)*words
> ```
>
> ### Detailed Description
>
> ---
>
> This object is improperly documented.
>
> Issue is that the list(char_ptr) is treated as a member function
>   instead of a type..

---

**question**

How can I fix the doxygen output to document `words` as member data ( not public member function ) ?

---

**Configuration attempts**

```
PROJECT_NAME           = "doxytest"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./build/docs
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES

TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = YES

HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = NO
INPUT                  = ./
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h *.c

GENERATE_HTML          = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO

ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES|NO **
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             =
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = list
```

** tried both YES and NO with all other settings the same ( asterisks not included ;)

```
PROJECT_NAME           = "doxytest"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES

TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = YES

HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = NO
INPUT                  = ./
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h *.c

GENERATE_HTML          = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO

ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             =
```

still not expanding the list(char_ptr) properly though. no change of output

i tried to replicate the working scenario ( discussed below ) on windows, by copy+pasting above config and list.h files :

[image: empty documentation produced on windows]

Comment: You have `EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF = YES`, which won't expand `list`. You can try setting that to no. Or you could try `PREDEFINED += list(x)=list_type_##x`. Didn't try either of these.

Comment: tried EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF = NO, and explicitly adding the macro definitions to PREDEFINED, neither fixed the issue

Comment: Note that a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=719591) about EXPAND_AS_DEFINED has been corrected in v1.8.6, Also, v1.7.4 has fixed some bugs with macro expansion.

Comment: Your problem seems to be not reproduced by other users. To help you more, could you share the complete configuration file (by saving it from the doxywizard) with all options? Share it via an internet clipboard, or what you want (but not in the OP, it's quite long ...).

Comment: @Bentoy13 ive added a link to the output I get from `doxygen -g`

Comment: @amdixon Humm ... no, it's the default configuration file, so we don't get _your_ configuration. Ok, let's try another thing: [here](http://www.wepaste.com/macro_doxygen-config/) is mine (with v1.8.9.1).

Comment: @Bentoy13 using yours worked ! the solution is somewhere in the difference between the two

Comment: @amdixon Such a relief! It was my last idea to find out what's going on with this problem. Good luck with that in hand!

Comment: @Bentoy13 on further analysis, now both the solution which you edited in answer below and my first configuration attempt are working. these were copy+paste tested not working earlier. either running doxygen with your default state fixed or some sort of browser caching led to false test results earlier.

Comment: @amdixon You're welcomed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Doxygen documentation

> EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF
>
> If the EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF and MACRO_EXPANSION tags are both set to YES then the macro expansion is limited to the macros specified with
>   the PREDEFINED and EXPAND_AS_DEFINED tags.
>
> The default value is: NO.
>
> This tag requires that the tag ENABLE_PREPROCESSING is set to YES.
>
> EXPAND_AS_DEFINED
>
> If the MACRO_EXPANSION and EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF tags are set to YES then this tag can be used to specify a list of macro names that should
>   be expanded. The macro definition that is found in the sources will be
>   used. Use the PREDEFINED tag if you want to use a different macro
>   definition that overrules the definition found in the source code.
>
> This tag requires that the tag ENABLE_PREPROCESSING is set to YES.

Thus the EXPAND_AS_DEFINED option will only work if the MACRO_EXPANSION option is specified as `yes` (which it is not).

So just specify `MACRO_EXPANSION` to be `yes` and add `list` to `EXPAND_AS_DEFINED`.  This will fix your problem.

**EDIT**

The following configuration (only relevant options) has been tested with Doxygen 1.8.5, 1.8.6 and 1.8.9.1 (under Win7):

```
PROJECT_NAME           = "doxytest"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES

TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = YES

HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = NO
INPUT                  = ./
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h *.c

GENERATE_HTML          = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO

ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             =
```

Other options are left to their default values.

The generated output is:

> ### improperlydocumented Struct Reference
>
> ---
>
> ```
> #include <list.h>
> ```
>
> ### Public Member Functions
>
> ---
>
> ```
> list_of_char_ptr* words
> ```
>
> ### Detailed Description
>
> ---
>
> This object is improperly documented.
>
> Issue is that the list(char_ptr) is treated as a member function
>   instead of a type..

Comment: thanks @randomusername, i added this attempt to my question ( if ive interpreted correctly ), but still same output

Comment: @amdixon Is it the exact same or has the new function definition become ``force_append_macro (list_of_, char_ptr) *words;``?

Comment: was the exact same ( and i deleted the html folder to avoid any possible caching issues in-between )

Comment: @amdixon I've tested this solution with Doxygen 1.8.5, it works fine. I even desactivate the option EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF, same good output. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Bentoy13 im on version 1.8.6.. does doxygen do any system caching ?

Comment: @amdixon I don't know, but I would do like you said, deleting the output folder between two runs. When I tested, it was the first run, and it worked, so no caching issue here.

Comment: @amdixon Tested with the same version of doxygen, works properly if you enable MACRO_EXPANSION. Sorry ...

Comment: @amdixon there could be some hidden files (files starting with a . ), make sure that there aren't any of them like that.

Comment: @amdixon No hidden files, default is to display them on my pc. My test is based on the content of list.h and only that; do you have the problem when running on this unique file (and not with all other files)? the keyword "list" may be already used elsewhere ... I don't know, it's an idea.

Comment: @Bentoy13 Could you either edit my answer or post your own with the exact configuration and the output of `doxygen -v` you used? It might help the OP see where they differ.

Comment: @randomusername Sure, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Bentoy13 No problem, it's no inconvenience at all for me really.

Comment: copy pasted this exact config file - still same output. im on ubuntu. running gcc version `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`. ill test this on windows using mingw tonight. what compiler are you using ?

Comment: @Bentoy13 no hidden files. And list.h is the only file in this project ( so will have exclusive dibs on list macro )

Comment: @amdixon I'm not sure that the compiler is relevant here, except if you want to rebuild doxygen from source ... anyway, I'm using VC2010. I've installed doxygen from the installer program.

Comment: @amdixon Tested with doxygen v1.8.3.1 under cygwin, works fine for this macro expansion (thought doc is not complete, the doc for list_of_char_ptr is not generated).

Comment: browser caching led to false test results earlier. now working on my system, and tested as working in a clean ubuntu vm..